# Why does hitting a force field drain its power supply?

Tags: science-fiction

This is basically an omnipresent concept with how force fields work in sci-fi, especially in video games: that the act of hitting a force field is what causes the force field to lose power and eventually fail. Oftentimes, a shield that's continuously in use but unneeded barely consumes any power at all. It's only when the shields are actually struck that they come any closer to running out.

But why would this be? It's not like the shield is a physical piece of armor that gets damaged and breaks. And it's not like the tech that's generating the shield is taking any damage. Presumably the thing that's generating the shield is safely *behind* the shield, just like every other part of the user or ship or mech the shield is protecting. And yet, whether it's for gameplay balance or the preservation of dramatic tension, it's frequently the case that the more damage a shield blocks, the less time the shield can hold out for.

**Why would this be? What is it about sci-fi force fields that causes the punishment the energy shield takes to have any impact on how long the shield lasts?**

Comment: Can you explain why force field work in your world. Because without knowing that, the answer must be the same as for force fields, "Because in my world force fields work" => "Because in my world hitting a force field drains it's power". Please remember that we're here to answer questions related to building your fictional world, not discussing genre conventions of existing works of fiction.

Comment: @sphennings This isn't for any specific setting. It's a nigh-omnipresent sci-fi trope that to my knowledge has never been justified.

Comment: Then this question is not a good fit for this site, since it isn't about building a fictional world.

Comment: @sphennings I'm pretty sure one of the rules here says a question should ideally be useful to people other than yourself, and the more specific to your setting it is, the worse it is.

Comment: That doesn't mean you can start a general discussion about forcefields in fiction. Questions need to be specific. To quote from the help center "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Comment: I have some potential answers to this question, but sphennings makes a reasonable point. It wouldn't take much rewriting to create a question of the form "_the shield generators in my world stop X kinds of weapon, resulting in some effect Y over time, why is this?_"

Comment: @sphennings, recently asked [this](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9602/is-it-ok-to-ask-questions-that-dont-have-specific-worldbuilding-use) question on meta, recieved +4/-0 votes.

Comment: @Firedestroyer even in that context, the question is too open-ended. It effectively asks "_enumerate all the ways in which a fictional energy shield might be damaged or depleted in use_". Without constraints, and without a reasonable metric for a good answer, it isn't a good fit for the site.

Comment: @StarfishPrime, You're probably right. The question has no explanation of details, so we can't make a proper answer.

Comment: One could reword this question in this way: There is a technology X. It performs this way. What is the most likely X? This question is not much different from other engineering and technological questions on this stack.

Answer (score 5):

The force field is actually not always there, in fact, most of the time it's not there at all.

This is because your force field use so much power that most of the time they are off to save power, there are sensors that turn sections of it on just in time to stop whatever was detected and then the force part gets turned off again.

This could have an interesting side effect, there will be an arms race on not just trying to overpower the field but also to get unnoticed by its sensor. There could be a couple of techniques for this but they might be better for another question.

Comment: This is a flawed concept. Force fields are generally held to protect against energy weapons including lasers... there's no "turning it on just in time" for things you can't see until they've already impacted you and done the damage.

Comment: @JohnO it can just as easily be a force field that reacts to outside stimuli. It'll barely register normally, but from a certain point It'll start 'pushing back', or counteracting the energy. This is much like pushing against a mountain. The mountain pushes equally hard back at you as you push at it. Only for the shield it costs energy. Also most games nowadays specifically don't use hitscan weapons.

Answer (score 2):

Force field generators have power requirements like any other active component (whether we're talking about electronics, or laser cannons, or what-have-you).

If they come under load (an attack), they *shunt* this attack's energy elsewhere. Maybe it's teleported to the intergalactic void. Or even in time itself, and blips into existence during the heat death of the universe. This is how it protects the ship or entity and fulfills its purpose.

The trouble is, of course, that the shunting of this energy isn't instantaneous. It can drain energy only slow quickly, and if the incoming (attack) energy is more than it can drain, then an attack of a continuous beam weapon that lasts 1 second might take 10 seconds to drain. The mechanism/effect/phenomenon "buffers" the remaining 9 seconds of energy, allowing the drain to eventually dissipate it.

So, for this sort of force field effect to make sense, any force field generator will have two important factors... how quickly it can drain energy, and how much it can buffer undrained energy. (If this is starting to sound like Niven/Pournelle's Langston fields, I'm not plagiarizing... I figure I'm just working through the same thought process they went through, 40 years later and not quite so cleverly.)

If at any point the buffer capacity is exceeded, then the force field generator itself becomes damaged rather thoroughly, and possibly other systems as well.

It might even be the case that the drain and buffer effects are separable... though it's unclear how useful a buffer-only system would be. You can tank alot of damage, but what happens if you have to shut down the force field generator? Where does that energy go? And a drain-only system would be be only minimally useful, because any attack that exceeds the drain capacity must do at least some damage (and if drain-only systems are powerful enough to eat any attack, then space operas become boring snoozefests).

If on popular television shows this is simplified to a "our shields are at 80%!", then I can only tell you, question-asker, that they call it the boob tube for a reason. But given the exigencies of battle and the need for an immediately quantifiable status upon which to make strategic decisions with, it's probably really the only way to do it.

So, what can you change about this and what can you keep? Well, Niven's Langston field drains the energy in a somewhat scientifically plausible way... it has to black-body-radiate that energy out from the field itself, over a matter of minutes/hours. But you can drain the energy however you like. It just "goes somewhere, but not here".

You can allow for refinements of how much can be drained, such that later models have a higher drain factor. Or impose hard limitations based upon your fictional science. Miniaturization (or not). Same with buffer factor (though I recommend that there be harder limits with it).

These can be limited to certain types of energy, if you prefer. Only certain particles are blockable, only certain frequencies of EM. Maybe it does kinetic energy (or not), or even just throttles that. Mix and match as you see fit.

There are other factors that impose strategic considerations... what is the maximum extent from the location of the shield generator? What shapes can the manifold be? Does the force field have to remain spherical? If you extend the shields outward to double the initial radius, how much weaker is it, or how much more power does the generator draw? Does it even have to be bounded at all, or can they extend a square-shaped shield directly in front of them? Can the shield be tuned to more easily block some energies (at the expense of being less effective blocking others)?

There are other factors that impose narrative considerations. For instance, what happens if the astronaut in a spacesuit drifts slowly up against it? In some fictions, when a shield is activate that would cross the boundary of solid matter, it is slice off as if with the sharpest knife in the universe. That's always struck me as implausible, but on the other hand we know that if your force fields protect against columnated neutron beams, the only way to drain those away is for some sort of matter-to-energy effect to be in play. And if it can do that, why not protons, electrons, and even whole atoms? It might be that this force field could slice and dice solid matter.

All of these issues are beyond the scope of your original question though, and will need to be determined based on the needs of your story, your own personal taste in science fiction, and how much it will annoy your audience.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple: hitting the force field damages the field itself, like you were hitting a physical object. The field generator then has to replace the damaged parts by making "more field." Making more field happens extremely quickly but costs energy. When the generator runs out of energy, it can't repair anymore.

This is often used in fiction where someone will focus damage on one part of the field to punch through - causing damage to one small part of the field faster than the field generator can repair it.